# Bounds on $E[(f(X)-g(X))^2]$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am looking for good upper bounds on $E[(f(X)-g(X))^2]$. For example, here are two bound that I derived:
$$
E[(f(X)-g(X))^2] \le E[4 \max(f(X)^2, g(X)^2)]
$$
where I used $(x-y)^2 \le 4 \max(x^2,y^2)$. Unfortunatly, this bounds is still hard to compute since it is not true that $ E[4 \max(f(X)^2, g(X)^2)] \le  4 \max(E[f(X)^2, E[g(X)^2])$ .  At least I don't think so.

Another, bound uses $(x-y)^2 \le 2x^2+2y^2$ then
$$
E[(f(X)-g(X))^2] \le 2E[f(X)^2]+2E[g(X)^2]
$$

I was wondering if there are batter bounds that are easy to compute?

Comment: Note that your second inequality proves that the first inequality really can be written as $E[(f(x)-g(x))^2] \leq 4 \max(E[f(x)^2],E[g(x)^2])$. So your second inequality is strictly better.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think we can derive better inequalities?

Comment: If $X$ takes values in $\mathbb R^2$, then $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ could be the two separate scalar components, and for certain distributions of $X$ those are independent, and it's just as if you're looking for bounds on $\operatorname{E}((U-V)^2)$ for independent random variables $U,V$.  If $X$ is real-valued, one can do similar things but I expect it takes somewhat more work. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ \lvert E[f(X) g(X)] \rvert \leq \sqrt{E[f(X)^2] E[g(X)^2]}. $$
This then gives you, after expanding out the brackets and refactoring,
$$ E[(f(X)-g(X))^2] \leqslant \left( (E[f(X)^2])^{1/2} + (E[g(X)^2])^{1/2} \right)^2 $$

Comment: I am trying to see how you did the expansion but I can't. I get that $E[(f(x)-g(x))^2]=E[(f(x))^2]-2E[f(x)g(x)]+E[g(x)^2]$. But since the term $E[f(x)g(x)]$ is with the minus you are lower bounding. What am I missing?

Comment: @Boby You don't know the sign of $E[fg]$. What you do know is that for real numbers, $ -|a| \leq a \leq |a| $ (one of these is an equality, of course, but that's not the point.) Taking $a=-E[fg]$ gives you the next inequality you need.

Comment: I see, you basically upper bounded $-2E[f(x)g(x)] \le 2|E[f(x)g(x)]|$.

Comment: Do you think your inequality can be improved or is it almost tight?

Comment: Ha. You basically just showed Minkovski inequality with $p=2$.

Comment: @Boby Yep, you caught me ;). And therefore you know it is tight.